# How to sort bytes in string?

Tags: go

I wanted to sort the characters in a string, but didn't work as expected:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

func getKey(str string) string {
    bs := []byte(str)
    sort.Slice(bs, func(a, b int) bool {
        return str[a] < str[b]
    })
    return string(bs)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", getKey("nat"))
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", getKey("tan")) // expect to get "ant", but got "atn"
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", getKey("tan") == getKey("nat"))
}
```

I expect it to print:

```
ant
ant
true
```

But actually printed:

```
ant
atn
false
```

https://play.golang.org/p/CtozIz0M6_K

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are sorting `bs`, but using `str` for comparison:

```
sort.Slice(bs, func(a, b int) bool {
    return str[a] < str[b]
})
```

The `bs := []byte(str)` operation copies the string to a byte array and creates a slice from it. So as you sort you move chars in the `bs` slice, but compare the chars in the original string, and those are not moved by the sort.

Use the correct comparison:

```
sort.Slice(bs, func(a, b int) bool {
    return bs[a] < bs[b]
})
```